# Inconvenient of @Value Annotation in Spring 3.0

Tags: spring, annotations

I'm wondering if I add a @Value annotation on a property, the class who contains this property cannot be used by another one with a different value, Example :

MyClassUtil.java had

```
@Value("${some.value}")
private int _myProperty;
```

And of course there is one module.properties who contain :

```
some.value=10
```

Another class ClassA.java wants to use this class with value 10. Ok, no problem.
But another class ClassB.java wants to use this class but with another value : 20. I cannot do this if I'm not mistaken. 
Because before @Value era, I could declare two beans in the moduleContext.xml without any problem.

So, is @Value pushes you to do some strong coupling ?

Comment: some.value will indeed have one value - why not some.valueA and some.valueB. Or just drop the value annotation, it appears in appropriate

Comment: For the value to be different, you would need to have two properties file with the same key, but different value. You can then have two contexts with different property sources, each generating a qualified bean of type `MyClassUtil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the annotation configuration can not be instance specific. It is important to understand the concept of **bean definitions** in bean factory.

Manual bean definition:

- Single `<bean>` element in your XML config leads to a single bean definition. Multiple `<bean>` mean multiple definitions (regardless of a bean type).
- Single `@Bean` method within `@Configuration` class leads to a single bean definition. Multiple `@Bean` methods mean multiple definitions (regardless of a bean type).

However when using **component scan**, classes annotated with `@Component`-like annotations are *auto-registered* as a single bean definition. There is no way you can register bean multiple times via **component scan**.

Similarly, **annotation configurations** (`@Value`, `@Autowired`, etc.) are type-wide. Your bean instances are always augmented and processed with the same effect (e.g. injecting the same value). There is no way you can alter annotation processing behaviour from instance to instance.

Is this tight coupling? **It is not in its general understanding** - bean factory (Spring) is still free to inject whatever it thinks is suitable. However it is more of a *service lookup* pattern. This simplifies your life when working with **domain specific singletons**. And most beans in an application context tend to be singletons, many of them domain specific (controllers, services, DAOs). Framework singletons (non-project specific reusable classes) should never use annotation based configuration - in this scope, **it is an unwanted tight coupling**.

**If you need different bean instances, you should not use annotation configuration and define your beans manually.**